# UIDatePicker to show year only

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there a way to have a UIDatePicker show year only?

Comment: It would help to understand more if you can paste your codes.

Answer (score 15):

I have a little code that I was about to delete, but the snippet is better off if it is online somewhere. It's not amazing, but it is searchable!

**Objective-C code to create an array of all years since 1960**. Perfect for input into a `UIPicker`

```
//Get Current Year into i2
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
int i2  = [[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];


//Create Years Array from 1960 to This year
years = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=1960; i<=i2; i++) {
    [years addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
```

The `UIPickerView` data source and delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView*)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [years count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [years objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Don't forget the declaration in the interface

```
//Data
NSMutableArray *years;
```

The out put of it is

[image]

Referenced from [here](http://divya-ioscoder.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/uipicker-iphone-sdk-populated-with-year.html)

Comment: Rocking on StackOverflow.. Great.. !! is your company providing training to freshers in iPhone development?

Comment: Actually, No. It's just new department to developed in my company

Comment: I would hope that a programming 101 student would know how to create an array of year values after the second week of the class.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this with `UIDatePicker`, but you can with `UIPicker`.

You need to create an array for the years, and add them to the `UIPicker` using the `UIPicker` delegates

[Here](http://divya-ioscoder.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/uipicker-iphone-sdk-populated-with-year.html)'s a tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment, but I was playing around with the answer by Wolvorin and I decided to do a way where the most recent year would be at the top of the Picker.  Currently, his code goes oldest to most recent years.

All I changes was in my NSMutableArray setup in the viewDidLoad instead of his:

```
//Create Years Array from 1960 to This year
years = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=1960; i<=i2; i++) {
    [years addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
```

I used:

```
years = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i1=i2; i1<=i2 & i1>=1920; i1--) {
    [years addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i1]];
}
```

Which does the for in reversed order going from the most recent date, then subtracting one year  (and adding it to the Array) until it gets to 1920.

My formula:

```
int i1=i2; i1<=i2 & i1>=1920; i1--
```

Answer (score 3):

Just updating the existing answer in this post with **Swift 3**:

```
var yearsTillNow : [String] {
    var years = [String]()
    for i in (1970..<2018).reversed() {
        years.append("\(i)")
    }
    return years
}
```

Just use this for your `UIPickerView` datasource.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to set only Year and Month. Only these modes are available as of iOS 13.5.1

> - time: A mode that displays the date in hours, minutes, and (optionally) an AM/PM designation. The exact items shown and their
>   order depend upon the locale set. An example of this mode is [ 6 | 53
>   | PM ].
> - date: A mode that displays the date in months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the locale
>   setting. An example of this mode is [ November | 15 | 2007 ].
> - dateAndTime: A mode that displays the date as unified day of the week, month, and day of the month values, plus hours, minutes, and
>   (optionally) an AM/PM designation. The exact order and format of these
>   items depends on the locale set. An example of this mode is [ Wed Nov
>   15 | 6 | 53 | PM ].
> - countDownTimer: A mode that displays hour and minute values, for example [ 1 | 53 ]. The application must set a timer to fire at the
>   proper interval and set the date picker as the seconds tick down. [UIDatePicker.Mode - developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/mode)

---

You may build it using a custom UIPickerView.

```
class DatePickerViewController: UIViewController {
    var dates =  [Date]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        
        var date = Date().addYear(n: -10)
        let endDate = Date().addYear(n: 10)
        
        repeat {
            date = date.addMonth(n: 1)
            dates.append(date)
        } while date < endDate
        
        
        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(picker)
        
        picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
    }
}


extension  DatePickerViewController: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dates.count
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let date = self.dates[row]
        return date.stringDate()
    }
    
    func view(forRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label =  UILabel()
        return label
    }
}

extension  DatePickerViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let date = self.dates[row]
        // Date that the user select. 
        print( date, date.stringDate())
    }
}


extension Date {
    public  func addYear(n: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: n, to: self)!
    }
    
    public  func addMonth(n: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: n, to: self)!
    }
    
    public  func stringDate() -> String {
        let calendar  = Calendar.current
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.timeZone = calendar.timeZone
        dateFormatter.locale = calendar.locale
        // Use YYYY to show year only. 
        // Use MMMM to show month only. 
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMM YYYY")
        
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: self)
        return dateString
    }
}
```

---

Just change the following two lines- add/subtract as many years you wish to show.

```
var date = Date().addYear(n: -10) 
let endDate = Date().addYear(n: 10)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I changed Sharukh Mastan's code slightly to always show the current year on top.

```
var formattedDate: String? = ""

let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "yyyy"
formattedDate = format.string(from: date)

var yearsTillNow: [String] {
    var years = [String]()
    for i in (Int(formattedDate!)!-70..<Int(formattedDate!)!+1).reversed() {
        years.append("\(i)")
    }
    return years
}

print(yearsTillNow)
```

This prints an array of years going back for 70 years which you can use as UIPickerView datasource

Comment: Any possible way to share the code to work onlyyyy for years, and to start the picker after clicking in a textfield, I already tried but didnt reach a solution

Comment: This is already only years, also this link should help with getting the picker with the textfield: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828398/show-datepicker-on-textfield-tap

Comment: When i added the whole code and replaced this part, months still appeared. and thank you for the link

Comment: Thats odd, for me the line " format.dateFormat = "yyyy" " is what makes it to just year as we can see on this website with lokale set to en_US_POSIX: https://nsdateformatter.com/ Maybe check your lokale here and see what format you want.