# Show datepicker on textfield tap

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I'm very new to iOS so obviously I'm missing a few concepts when trying to follow this solution [Display datepicker on tapping on textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074683/display-datepicker-on-tapping-on-textfield)  to my problem.

I have the interface and implementation in a class called DatepickerAppDelegate, but I'm lost here:

*"In the XIB, Pull out a UIToolbar and a UIDatePicker but don't attach it to the view. Connect the outlets appropriately. dateChanged: responds to changes in the date picker and doneEditing: is called when the Done button in the tool bar is clicked. Connect them too. The methods are implemented as listed below."*

I read something about XIB's but I'm using a storyboard, so I think I don't have then. Also, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to pull out elements without attaching it to my view controllers (I'm trying, but when I release the mouse button, the tool flies back to the toolbar), and I don't even understand why I need a UIToolbar.

And finally, how do I connect my textfield to the datepicker delegate?

Can someone help me?

UPDATE:

In fact it is very simple, I just need to:

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

self.birthday.inputView = datePicker;
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`UIResponder`, from which `UITextField` inherits, [defines a property called `inputView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW22).  This property (a `UIView *`) can define a view that will be displayed *instead of the keyboard* when that `UIResponder` becomes the first responder.

Thus, if you want a `UIDatePicker` to appear when you tap in a textField (ie, you make that textField the first responder), then you can say, naïvely:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init...];
... configure datePicker ...

[myTextField setInputView:datePicker];
```

Now, when your `UITextField` is tapped, a `UIDatePicker` will be brought up instead.

## HOWEVER

You'll want to do more than this, because you'll need to handle different orientations and different idioms.

But that's the basic idea.

(And if you want a toolbar above the `UIDatePicker`, that's what the `inputAccessoryView` property is for...)

Comment: I wrote an open source class, [STADateField](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/blob/master/STAControls/STAControls/TextField/STADateField.h), based upon this answer.

Answer (score 21):

*In viewDidLoad of* **ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [txtFieldBranchYear setInputView:datePicker];
}
```

*Add one method in your ViewController*

```
-(void) dateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)txtFieldBranchYear.inputView;
    [picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *eventDate = picker.date;
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
    txtFieldBranchYear.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];
}
```

**txtFieldBranchYear** *is an outlet of UITextField*

Comment: Great answer. Just a simplification: `txtFieldBranchYear.text = dateString;` should also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Add a datepicker view and uitoolbarview to your view.
For example

```
CGFloat toolbarHeight = 44.f;
CGFloat datePickerHeight = 140.f;
CGFloat containerViewHeight = toolbarHeight+datePickerHeight;
//create container view for datepicker and toolbar
UIView *containerView = [[UIVIew alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, [self.view bounds].size.height+containerViewHeight, [self.view bounds].size.width, containerViewHeight)];

//after init toolbar set the frame
toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.f,0.f,containerView.frame.size.width, toolbarHeight];
//then add on toolbar button save and release it after add

//after init datePicker set the frame
datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, toolbarHeight, containerView.frame.size.width, datePickerHeight);

//add datePicker and toolBar to containerView
[containerView addSubview: toolBar];
[containerView addSubview: datePicker];

[toolBar release];
[datePicker release];

//add containerView to main view

[self.view addSubview: containerView];
[containerView release];
```

So when view did load they are will be hidden Y of contener view is outside of the your view frame.

Now you should assign property delegate of UITextFieldDelegate

```
textfield.delegate = self;
```

In the method of delegate **textFieldDidBeginEditing** see [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) you should fire method that will show your datePicker and toolbar.
If you have many textFields to define which is was selected use **tag** property, which is integer and you can use **switch** instead of many **if** conditions.

To show your datePicker and toolbar you should change the Y of containerView frame.
Here is how to do that

```
CGRect containerViewFrame = containerView.frame;
containerViewFrame.y -=containerViewHeight;
containerView.frame = containerViewFrame;
```

To hide just plus the containerViewHeight variable.
You can use UIViewAnimations to show it with some animation. For example **UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut**