# How to display UIDatePicker if user hit the UITextfield Programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'd like to Display UIDatePicker only when user the UITextField is Clicked. When the date is picked, it should be shown in the same UITextField.I want to implement UIDatePicker programmatically.I know how to write the  code of UITextField Programmatically.
I even don't know how to call the UIDatePicker.

Date of **Birth.m**

```
UITextField txtDOB=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 190, 300, 20)];

txtDOB.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;

txtDOB.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

[txtDOB setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

txtDOB.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

txtDOB.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

txtDOB.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentLeft;

txtDOB.delegate=self;

[self.view addSubview:txtDOB];
```

Comment: Possible duplication : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828398/show-datepicker-on-textfield-tap [1].. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197855/iphone-display-date-picker-on-textfield-click[2]..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074683/display-datepicker-on-tapping-on-textfield[3]...

Comment: This is not duplicate question yar.check it yar. ok thank u for responding.....It is not duplicate question......

Comment: @DhavalBhadania Check you first, one of the link is broken.

Answer (score 38):

The easiest way is to implement the `datePicker` is  as following:

Create the `datePicker:`

```
self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[self.datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(onDatePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then link the `datePicker` to the `textfield` inputView:

```
self.textField.inputView = self.pickerView;
```

In the end you can catch the action when a date was picked, and convert the date to a string, to show the selected date in the `textField`

```
- (void)onDatePickerValueChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
{
    self.textField.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
}
```

Comment: A NSDateFormatter property, I'm using it to convert the date to a string

Answer (score 7):

```
    UIDatePicker *picker1   = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 210, 320, 216)];
    [picker1 setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    picker1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [picker1 addTarget:self action:@selector(startDateSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//    [picker1 addSubview:toolBar];
    self.birthTxt.inputView  = picker1; // Here birthTxt is Textfield Name replace with your name
```

Comment: This is the best way to add date picker to textfield and get default keybaord like animation and behaviour.

Comment: Yup !! and quit easy to implement in terms of Line of Code @HarshIT

Comment: @IDeveloper. Thanks for response.But it is not working brother.If i hit the textfield  the UIDatePicker will not displayed

Comment: Can you please update your code so that i can edit and give you back @user2930730

Answer (score 2):

Before going to this code, you need to just know about `UIActionSheet` and You need to implement `UIActionShetDelegate` and `UITextFieldDelegate` In the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` you need to show the action sheet as below:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
   UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Date" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Select", nil];
  [asheet showInView:[self.view superview]];
  [asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];
}

- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
  {
    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 240)];

   [pickerView setMinuteInterval:5];
   [pickerView setTag: DatePickerTag];

  [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
  NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];

  [[subviews objectAtIndex:SelectButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 250, 280, 46)];
  [[subviews objectAtIndex:CancelButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 280, 46)];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

- First indicate that your class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol
- Then in `viewDidLoad`  set the `delegate` and `tag` of your text field.

  ```
   yourTextField.delegate = self;  
   yourTextField.tag = 111;
  ```
- Then implement the following delegate method:

  ```
  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {   
      if (textField.tag==111) {  
          [self showDatePicker];  
      }  
      return YES;  
  }
  ```
- Now implement a function `showDatePicker`

  ```
  - (void)showDatePicker {  
      datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
      datePicker.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

      UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init];
      [toolbar sizeToFit];

      UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(showSelectedDate)];    

      doneBtn.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  

      UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];    

      toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1];  

      [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft,doneBtn ,nil]];  

      [yourTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];  

      yourTextField.inputView = datePicker;   
  }
  ```

OR you can do it simply in your `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]init]; 

[toolbar sizeToFit];    

 UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self
 action:@selector(showSelectedDate)];    

 doneBtn.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  

 UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
 target:nil action:nil];    

toolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:5.0/255.0 green:110.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1];  

[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, doneBtn , nil]];  

[yourTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];  

yourTextField.inputView = datePicker;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a proper selector when editing begins on UITexfield, use below code

```
 [txtDOB addTarget:self action:@selector(textbeginEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

And then implelemt the textbeginEditing method to open the datepicker.

```
-(void)textbeginEditing:(id)sender{

UIActionSheet __autoreleasing * date_sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select the date" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

date_sheet.tag = 2;

[date_sheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.hidden = NO;
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];

// Implement the method labelChange
 [datePicker addTarget:self
                action:@selector(labelChange:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


[date_sheet addSubview:datePicker];

UISegmentedControl __autoreleasing *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];

closeButton.momentary = YES;    
closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);    
closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;    
closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dissmissDatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[date_sheet addSubview:closeButton];
[date_sheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];    
[date_sheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
}
```

labelChange method implementation

```
-(void)labelChange:(UIDatePicker *)sender{
NSDateFormatter __autoreleasing *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
 dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
 NSString *dateString =  [dateFormat stringFromDate:sender.date];
 txtDOB.text = dateString; 
}
```

Comment: @GGyanendra singh. Thanks for your response.But it will not working brother.getting some errors in "labelChange method implementation."

Comment: txtDOB.text = date, this line might be causing the error. Declare this as ivar in (.h file) or get the instance of the text field by tag.e.g. UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:i]; //tag set for txtDOB textfield.

Comment: No brother... NSLog(@"****** The date is %@", creationDate);   NSString *date =  [dateFormat stringFromDate:sender.date];
    txtDOB.text = date; These two lines are errors brother

Comment: I would say why don't you use the UIButton with the same background image as textfield (it will mimic as textfield). I have done it a lot a it's east too.

Comment: ok brother if u have the code of UIButton with the same background image as textfield, please update the code.

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074683/display-datepicker-on-tapping-on-textfield?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828398/show-datepicker-on-textfield-tap?lq=1

Comment: Create the button programmatically (like you are doing for textfield), change the background image of it using " [btnDOB setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"txtfield.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal] add selector using [btnDOB addTarget:self action:@selector(textbeginEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This will be simple, try this
When U click the textField, this method is called.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
```

Then, we dont want to display the keyboard.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Then, to display the datePicker

```
datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setFrame:CGRectMake(<ur dimension>)];
datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(done) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

This will display the datePicker.
Then U want to display the selected value in textField

```
-(void)done
{
  NSString *dateStri=[dateFormater stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    [timingTextField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateStri]];
}
```

Try this, and update me the  result

Comment: U got this? validate my answer

Answer (score -1):

First make userIntraction enable

`[txtDOB setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

and add your picker view as input view of this text filed

`[txtDOB setInputView:pickerview]`