# pop up date picker to set a date

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to make a pop-up date picker (DATE ONLY) when a user clicks on a button and set the selected date in my code.

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:8];
[comps setMonth:9];
[comps setYear:2018];
NSDate *earlier = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];
```

I can manually set a date by typing like this but I don't know how to set the date from the date picker. How do I do it?

Comment: There are many answers on the stackoverflow here is the one among them it has all your require code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011968/how-to-display-uidatepicker-if-user-hit-the-uitextfield-programmatically
\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is

> 1. Add NSDatePicker to your view and set the settings as needed in Storyboard.
> 2. Connect the delegates and iboutlets.
> 3. Then get and set the date as follows

```
NSDate *myDate = myDatePicker.dateValue; // get
myDatePicker.dateValue = myDate; // set
```