# Custom dialog on TextField tap?

Tags: flutter, dialog, textfield

My question is similar to [Show datepicker on textfield tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828398/show-datepicker-on-textfield-tap) but I need to do this in Flutter.

I have a TextField showing a date an I want to pop up a date dialog when user taps on it.

Is there another widget I should use instead of a TextField for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
           TextField(
             onTap: () => print('tapped'),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                    hintText: 'Enter a search term'),

            );
```

Comment: sorry updated code, just add onTap to textField just replace the print statement with your alert dialog call

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: as far as I know there's no widget specifically for this purpose.

Long answer: It depends on what you want to do after choosing the date. Another simple solution is to use a `FlatButton` for this. It does not have the unnecessary styling of a `TextField` that you seem not to want and at the same time gives the user some feedback of the tap.

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // call your dialog
  },
  child: Text(
    "Select date",
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield#-readme-tab-), it does exactly want you want to achieve.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';

// ...

class BasicDateField extends StatelessWidget {
  final format = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      DateTimeField(
        format: format,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                    labelText: "Tanggal Lahir"),
        onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
          return showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              firstDate: DateTime(1900),
              initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
              lastDate: DateTime(2100));
        },
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you recommend using some package, show how does it solve the issue.