# How can i create a year only Picker View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uidatepicker

first time posting here, so hope i am doing this right.

I am trying to create a picker or date picker that allows me to display only the years from 1900 to this year(2015).
so it should looking something like:

" Year house was built: *picker of years between 1900-2015* "

The only way i can think to do this is with a Picker View and an array of 115 values and i don't believe this is the right way.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated and apologies if i am using the website wrongly.

Comment: Did you look at using a date picker?

Comment: Yes i did, there are only four modes available they are, Date and Time, Time, Date, Count Down Timer.  I need exclusively just the year.

Comment: Why don't you think using a `UIPickerView` is right? Sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: Because i'd need an array of 115 numbers, could i loop through a date range in Swift?

Comment: P.S.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017791/uidatepicker-to-show-year-only

Comment: @MatthewGhent Yes, exactly. Just store your years as an array of `Int`s. Swift has a super neat syntax for iterating ranges: `for year in 1900...2015 { }`.

Comment: @MatthewGhent Oh just remembered there's an even better syntax for this in Swift... arrays can be initialised with a range directly, so actually you can just write: `let years = Array(1900...2015)`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a `UIPickerView` and a simple for-loop statement to build the years and fill the `UIPickerView`

```
for (var i=1899; i<2015; i++) 
array[i] = i + 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks exactly like what i need, will try implement it now.