# How to show year only in NSDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdatepicker

I want to show year component only in a NSDatePicker.

I tried set/add NSDateFormatter to NSDatePicker, but with no luck. (By dragging a NSDateFormatter to NSDatePicker in nib)

Is there any way to achieve this without subclassing NSDatePicker or NSTextField? Thank you!

Comment: If it's just a column of year numbers, in what sense is this about "dates" at all? You're just picking an integer from a list of integers. There is no need of a date picker for that.

Comment: I think this [Show year in NSDatePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017791/uidatepicker-to-show-year-only) link will helpful for you checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSDatePicker setDatePickerElements:]` can no longer be tricked into showing year only.

A year-only NSDatePicker can be obtained by configuring a year-month picker and subclassing NSDatePickerCell to prevent it from creating the month and separator fields:

```
- (void)_addSubfieldForElement:(int)arg1 withDateFormat:(id)arg2 referenceStrings:(id)arg3
{
    if ((arg1 == 6) || (arg1 == 100)) {
        return;
    }

    [super _addSubfieldForElement:arg1 withDateFormat:arg2 referenceStrings:arg3]; // Private API
}
```

Please file bug reports with Apple to request a year-only variant of NSDatePicker. I also requested a week-of-year picker.

Comment: I'm considering file a bug with Apple. But I guess Apple just want us do it by subclassing either NSDatePicker or NSTextField + stepper button.

Answer (score 2):

After diving into Apple's Documentation, I found the solution and want to post it here, in case it is useful for someone else.

No need to subclass `NSDatePicker`, there is a method `- (void)setDatePickerElements:(NSDatePickerElementFlags)elementFlags` which specifies which element the date picker would display. *elementFlags* is a constant, defined by a enum as:

> ```
> enum {
>    NSHourMinuteDatePickerElementFlag       = 0x000c,
>    NSHourMinuteSecondDatePickerElementFlag = 0x000e,
>    NSTimeZoneDatePickerElementFlag         = 0x0010,
>    NSYearMonthDatePickerElementFlag        = 0x00c0,
>    NSYearMonthDayDatePickerElementFlag     = 0x00e0,
>    NSEraDatePickerElementFlag              = 0x0100,
> };
> typedef NSUInteger NSDatePickerElementFlags;
> ```

When looking at those constants, I find it is just a bit mask. Bit place and the corresponding calendar elements is as follows:

15 - 9 bit: Unknown. Maybe unused.

8 bit: Era. (Would not display anything if has a 4-digit year format.)

7 bit: Year.

6 bit: Month.

5 bit: Day.

4 bit: Time zone.

3 bit: Hour.

2 bit: Minute.

1 bit: second.

0 bit: Unknown. Maybe millisecond, or unused.

So, the following line would give me a year only date picker:

```
[_yearOnlyDatePicker setDatePickerElements:0x0080];
```

`_yearOnlyPicker` is an instance of NSDatePicker.

Here is the result:

How `yearOnlyDatePicker` looks like in Interface Builder:

[image: In interface builder.]

How `yearOnlyDatePicker` looks like when running the app:

[image: When running the app.]

Comment: This does not work in OS X 10.11 or later. OS X 10.10 not tested. But it does work for OS X 10.9 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy you don't need to use NSDatePicker. All you have to do is create a range of years you want and use it as `datasource` for normal picker.

```
for (int i=1900; i<=currentYear; i++) {
  [_yourDataSourceArr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
}
```